# find the node value in xDocument

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, model-view-controller

I am unable to get the value.

How to get the `StatusDescription` value? Please tell me.

```
<WebServiceResponse xmlns="ws.abc.com">
  <SubscriptionInfo xmlns="ws.abc.com">
    <LicenseStatusCode>0</LicenseStatusCode>
    <Amount>0</Amount>
  </SubscriptionInfo>
  <VerificationResponse xmlns="www.abc.com">
    <VerificationResult>
      <ServiceStatus>
        <StatusNbr>304</StatusNbr>
        <StatusDescription>Address Not Found</StatusDescription>
      </ServiceStatus>
      <ServiceResult />
    </VerificationResult>
  </VerificationResponse>
</WebServiceResponse>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xml contains namepace and using XDocument you can get desired node value following way:

```
 XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

 XNamespace xmlNamespace = "www.abc.com";
 var ResultNode = from a in doc.Descendants(xmlNamespace + "VerificationResponse").Descendants(xmlNamespace + "StatusDescription")
                  select a.Value;
```

[WORKING DOTNET FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gwoJCh)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this (using Linq-to-XML)

```
// define the XML namespace of the <VerificationResponse> node and down
XNamespace wwwabc = "www.abc.com";

// parse your XML into a XDocument
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(your-xml-input);

// get the <StatusDescription> node(s) from the XDocument
// here I'm assuming there's only one such node, so I'm using
// the .FirstOrDefault() method to fetch it
var statusDescriptionNode = xdoc.Descendants(wwwabc + "StatusDescription").FirstOrDefault();

// if we found a first such node
if (statusDescriptionNode != null)
{
    string statusDescription = statusDescriptionNode.Value;
}
```

Of course, if this is a really large and complex XML, then the `.Descendants()` call might not be very efficient (it just searches the entire XML document for nodes of that namespace + node name).